# How to type text in a rubymotion functional test?

Tags: rubymotion

What I would like is to have a something like this, but I couldn't find something like the *type_text*  method in the docs:

```
describe "login controller" do
  tests LoginController

  it "lets you login" do
    type_text('user@example.com', :into => 'Email address') # Made up method
    type_text('mypassword', :into => 'Password') # Made up method

    tap('Login')

    view('Login succes!').should.not == nil
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That is a nice question. One would think that there is something in the toolkit to achieve this...

The only thing I know of would be a little detour. You select the view that stores the data like here: http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/testing/#_finding_views

And then simply change the text property of the view.

Comment: I guess for now I will have to live with `view('label').text = 'whatever'`, but I don't like it too much so I will leave the question open for now... thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to tell the simulator keyboard to press a key. You have to simply set the text directly in the test.